# How to run the application continously without hanging in background

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem in running the application continuously without hanging (Appending Data).
I want to run this code without hanging in background for every 5 seconds.

My code is:

```
    public void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button1.Text == "Start")
        {
            Timer1.Interval = 5000;
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
            Button1.Text = "Stop";
        }
        else if (Button1.Text == "Stop")
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            Button1.Text = "Start";
        }
    }
```

Comment: try increase time interval. please provide error message if you are getting any

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Put the process that causes UI hanging, (Timer1_Tick in your code) in `DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)` method and invoke it by calling `RunWorkerAsync`.
There's a nice tutorial at http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Remember not to use any thread-specific variable in the `DoWork` method. You have to pass them as paramaters to the method.

**UPDATE:** Here's what your code should look like:
*Not Tested*

```
public void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
  var bgw = new BackGroundWorker();
  bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
  }  

void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
  // Put you try-catch block here.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can implement it as Windows service, which will run in background of your system without showing explicitly. In the main thread you can perform required actions with 5 second delays.

Comment: i created this code for windows Form Application not for Windows Service